# How I can assign value to variable using a button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to write a graphic calculator using tkinter.

How can I assign a value to a variable using a button?

I wrote this code:

```
from tkinter import *

kalkulator = Tk()

a=0

def button_0a():
    a=0
    return 0

button0= Button(kalkulator, text="0", command=button_0a)

button0.grid(row=1, column=0)

kalkulator.mainloop()
```

This changes the value of a, but the next time it's pressed, I want it to change the value of b. How can I achieve this?

Comment: what research have you done to solve this problem? There are many questions related to building calculators on this site, and on passing values to the callback.

Answer (score 0):

`przycisk_0a` is your callback function bind to the `button0` button, so you must define your function, but you have defined the `button0` button which is **nonsense**. 
It must be like this:

```
def przycisk_0a():
```

Answer (score 0):

This changes the value of a and then changes the value of b the next time you press the button.

```
from tkinter import *

kalkulator = Tk()

a=0
b=0

def button_0a():
    b=0
    return 0

def button_0a():
    a=0
    button0.configure(command = button_0b)
    return 0

button0= Button(kalkulator, text="0", command=button_0a)

button0.grid(row=1, column=0)

kalkulator.mainloop()
```